# SSIS exit code error with batch file

Tags: r, batch-file, ssis

I have a pretty basic batch script which will run fine if I execute it alone.
When i try to place this batch file in an SSIS Executre Process Task i get the following error:

> [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program
>   Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\R.exe" "CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave
>   C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\Daily_Risk_Model_Script.R" at "", The process
>   exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

The script i have in the batch file is:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\Daily_Risk_Model_Script.R"
```

And in the execute process task I have:

```
Executable: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\bin\R.exe
Arguments: CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave C:\Users\aaaa\Documents\Daily_Risk_Model_Script.R
```

What am I missing? I have tried slightly different systax with no luck.

MS Visual Studio 2010

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following as the last line of your batch file to set the exit code to 0:

```
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: One step closer, i was able to get the task to complete in BIDS put now i error out when trying to execute from SQL Server Agent.

Comment: Usually, when something works in BIDS and not with Agent, either you forgot to publish or there is a rights issue with Agent's account.